# Vanilla Queue Creation

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

This used to work with the chronicle queue v3. It does not create a queue in v4. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Chronicle chronicleSignal = ChronicleQueueBuilder.vanilla("somePath").build();

ExcerptAppender appender = chronicleSignal.createAppender();

Answer (score 0):

The queue creation was hindered because it was in the same directory with an indexed one. It seems v4 doesn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

Queue v4 should ignore any files it doesn't recognise the extension for `.cq4` however Queue v3 didn't do this. You should make sure there is no other files places in the directories for Q v3